# lxml: XML validation with XMLSchema doesn't give error's position

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd, lxml

Here is python code referencing to valid XML-schema(1.xsd) and arbitrary XML (1.xml):

**1.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="product"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<my-product/>
```

**main.py:**

```
from lxml.etree import XMLParser, XMLSchema, parse, XMLSyntaxError

parser = XMLParser(schema=XMLSchema(file='1.xsd'))
try:
    xml = parse(open('1.xml', mode='rb'), parser)
except XMLSyntaxError as e:
    for error in parser.error_log:
        print error.message, error.line, error.column
```

**Output:**

> Element 'my-product': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. 0 0

**error.line** and **error.column** are always **0**.
How can I get an error position?

---

**UPD**

This code gives the correct position, but it has the lack of double parsing:

```
from lxml.etree import XMLParser, XMLSchema, parse, XMLSyntaxError, XML

schema=XMLSchema(file='1.xsd')
parser = XMLParser(schema=schema)

xml_file = open('1.xml', mode='rb')
xml = XML(xml_file.read())
if not schema.validate(xml):
    for error in schema.error_log:
        print error.message, error.line, error.column
else:
    xml = parse(xml_file, parser)
```

> Element 'my-product': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. 2 0

Comment: The xsd schema defines elements named `product`, but your element is named `my-product`.  I suppose it uses 0 0 because there is no element at all that matches the xsd, therefore it really has nothing specific to report.

Comment: I just gave a simple example. It doesn't matter what xml and where is the mistake. Anyway the right position is at line 2.

Comment: In your example, the real error is that the xsd defines an element named `product`, but the xml text contains no such elements.  That sort of error can't be nailed down to a specific line and column number, because it's perfectly okay to have elements in the xml that aren't in the xsd.  The validator validates the elements it knows about, and leaves the other elements alone.

Comment: You are not right. Try to play with code and you will figure it out.

Comment: I changed `<my-product/>` to `<product/>` in the xml, which removes the error.  I inserted arbitrary child elements inside `<product>`, which produces no errors.  Perhaps you could give an example that _does_ give an error with a specific line and column number.

Comment: @JohnGordon when an element is defined in xsd without any following specification it can be any type. With your changes XML doesn't produce an error because you made it conforming to XSD.

Comment: I can't explain why doing it one way flags line 2 as the error while the other way doesn't.  I assume it's because you're calling `schema.validate()` instead of calling  `parse()`; there must be some internal difference between the two.

Comment: I reported the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1599292